# How to properly check/evaluate Multiplexer design implementation?

Tags: digital-logic, multiplexer, logic-gates

I am not electrical engineer at all. I am just participating in [this course.](https://www.coursera.org/course/nand2tetris1)

I have been struggling for 2 days to implement Mux8Way16 - a multiplexer which has 8 different 16-bit inputs.

How can I design and implement digital logic to do this? Is this some mathematical tool or methodology used to design/implement this type of digital logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like you are trying to map a series of 8 16-bit signals to a 16-bit bus. The way to do it is to use an 8-bit MUX on each data bit i.e. 16 8-bit MUXs.

Think of each of the 16 MUXs as mapping one bit. So the MUX mapping bit 3 will take as inputs: bit 3 from signal 1, bit 3 from signal 2, bit 3 from signal 3 etc.

All the MUXs have their select lines connected together. So if you select the third signal, the bit 0 MUX will output bit 0 of the third signal, the bit 1 MUX will output bit 1 of the third signal etc.